# Different ways to define lists in Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala, if list1 below is not a list what is it?

```
scala> val list1 = (1,2,3)
res11: (Int, Int, Int) = (1,2,3)

scala> val list2 = List(1,2,3)
list2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: `list1` is a [tuple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_tuples.htm), not list per se

Comment: If you are interested in lists with can contain elements of different types (so called HList), then you should check out the [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`list1` is a `Tuple` or more specifically a `Tuple3` since it contains three elements.

Tuples can contain different types where as a `List` must contain elements of type you specify if it cannot be inferred.

Comment: Moreover `Tuple2` and `Tuple3` are different types, whereas a two element or three element `List` have the same type (have to keep type params in mind though).